# Work around to include null condition operator in .net version 4.0

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to include Null Condition Operator in a .net 4.0 application.

Migrating my application is a time consuming process and i would like to use this in 4.0 framework.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the link.

Comment: No problem. I actually have a couple of apps that use C# 6 targetting older frameworks. You need patches for some features (e.g. [Tasks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks/)) but for the most part it works quite nicely.